# Using Academic Years as x-Axis Labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(30)

data <- data.frame(group = factor(1:11), 
                   year = c(rep("2013-2014", times = 11), 
                            rep("2014-2015", times = 11), 
                            rep("2015-2016", times = 11), 
                            rep("2016-2017", times = 11)), 
                   value = runif(44),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data$plot_year <- as.Date(paste0("01/01/", substr(data$year, start = 1, stop = 4)), 
                     format = "%m/%d/%Y")

ggplot(data, aes(x = plot_year, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dotted") + 
  geom_line(data= data %>% 
                  filter(as.numeric(substr(plot_year, start = 1, stop = 4)) < 2015), 
            aes(x = plot_year, y = value, color = group)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

As we can see above, `2013` in the x-axis corresponds with `2013-2014`, `2014` corresponds with `2014-2015`, and so forth.

How can I use these axis labels - i.e., `2013-2014`, `2014-2015`, etc. - in place of the current x-axis labels? Every solution that I've found online has said to use `as.Date()` in some shape or form, but these are academic years and not a fixed date.

Comment: Why not just use `year` (which is academic year in your example) as the x variable?

Comment: Also, you can shorten your data creation code: `year = rep(paste0(2013:2016, "-", 2014:2017), each=11)`.

Comment: @eipi10 Maybe I'm missing something here, but using `year` in place of `plot_year` for the `ggplot` aesthetics omits the `geom_line`.

Comment: @eipi10 I.e., `ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dotted") + 
  geom_line(data= data %>% 
              filter(as.numeric(substr(year, start = 1, stop = 4)) < 2015), 
            aes(x = year, y = value, color = group)) + 
  theme_bw()`

Comment: Set the `group = group` in `aes` to use a discrete x variable with `geom_line`. Also, you don't need to add `aes` again if you've already specified; even if you change the data, it will still inherit.

Comment: Make `year` an ordered factor and you can subset using `<=` in the same way as with a numeric year. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the academic year directly as the x-value the plot. You can use comparison operators (like `<=`) for subsetting as long as `year` is a character or ordered factor (but not if `year` is a non-ordered factor). As a character variable, the ordering will be alphabetic. I prefer an ordered factor so that I can specify the order:

```
data$year = factor(data$year, levels=sort(unique(data$year)), ordered=TRUE)

ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group, group=group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dotted") + 
  geom_line(data= data %>% filter(year <= "2014-2015")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Although I prefer using the ordering of `year` for subsetting, you can also explicitly specify the years to be included:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group, group=group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dotted") + 
  geom_line(data= data %>% filter(year %in% c("2013-2014","2014-2015"))) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date to numeric and then use `scale_x_continuous` with *breaks* and *labels* parameter:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

# calculate the breaks as numeric corresponding to the dates
br <- as.numeric(as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01")))
# calculate the labels at each break
lb <- c("2013-2014", "2014-2015", "2015-2016", "2016-2017")

ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(plot_year), y = value, color = group)) +
          geom_point() + 
          geom_line(linetype = "dotted") + 
          geom_line(data= data %>% filter(year(plot_year) < 2015), 
                aes(x = as.numeric(plot_year), y = value, color = group)) + 
          theme_bw() + 
          scale_x_continuous(breaks = br, labels = lb) + xlab("year")
```

[image]